# Using SQLAlchemy session with HTTPServer. Thread Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I'm having an issue with using SQLAlchemy session with spawning a HTTP Server on a different thread (The reason I'm spawning the HTTP Server on another thread is because otherwise the Test just hangs forever). What is happening is that I'm passing the DB configuration within every request. But it's not allowing me to create a session on the test server that uses SQLite (dev server is PostgreSQL).  Every time it goes to the view it throws the following error:

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread.The object was created in thread id 5784 and this is thread id 8560
```

This is my test case:

```
class ViewsTestSuite(unittest.TestCase):


    def setUp(self):
        app = App(8000, testing=True)
        try:
            httpd_thread = threading.Thread(target=app.run)
            httpd_thread.daemon = True
            httpd_thread.start()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass
```

my application setup class:

```
class App:

    def __init__(self, port, testing=False):
        self.port = port
        self.testing = testing
        self.server = None
        self.config = None
        self.db = None

    def run(self):
        if self.testing:
            self.config = TestingConfig
        else:
            self.config = DevelopmentConfig
        self.init_db()
        RequestHandler.config = self.config
        self.server = HTTPServer(('localhost', self.port), RequestHandler)
        try:
            self.server.serve_forever()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass
        self.server.server_close()

    def stop(self):
        self.server.server_close()

    def init_db(self):
        self.db = Database(self.config.DATABASE_URL)
        self.db.create_session()
        self.db.create_database()
```

and the view I'm testing:

```
def get_recipes(handler):
    json_structure = []
    db = get_db(handler.config.DATABASE_URL)
    db.create_session()
    recipes = db.session.query(Recipe, func.coalesce(func.avg(Rating.rating).label('average'), 0)).\
        outerjoin(Rating).group_by(Recipe.id).all()
    for recipe in recipes:
        json_structure.append({
            "id": recipe[0].id,
            "name": recipe[0].name,
            "prep_time": recipe[0].prep_time,
            "vegeterian": recipe[0].vegeterian,
            "rating": float(recipe[1])
        })

    return 200, json.dumps(json_structure)
```

Any help would be really amazing! Thank you very much